# Review audit is telling me to use a link that doesn't exist?

Tags: support, review-audits

I was shown the below message when attempting to edit a review audit:

[image: To the right!?!]

For the image challenged:

> **Congratulations!**
>   This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. **You passed.** This post was already good enough to be useful, but it never hurts to make a good post even better. If you still want to edit it, use the link to the right to return to the post.

However, as you can see, the only thing to the right is the <kbd>Next</kbd> option for moving to the next review. Am I missing something super obvious or is this misleading?

Comment: I *believe* it's talking about the link underneath "active" in the question details. Definitely kind of misleading.

Answer (score 7):

It is talking about the link, laxly titled `link`, to the right of the question underneath the question details:

[image]

The wording is slightly misleading, and should probably say something like:

> If you still want to edit it, use the link *to the right of the question* to return to the post.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even see that little guy. I just used the question title, which seems to me much more prominent.